# Load vimeo hd thumbnails with NEW API

Tags: php, css, vimeo

I'm using code similar to this to load thumbnails of vimeo videos.

```
    <?php

        if(defined('AT_PROXY'))  {
              $aContext = array(
                  'http' => array(
                      'proxy' => AT_PROXY,
                      'request_fulluri' => true,
                  ),
              );
              $cxContext = stream_context_create($aContext);

              $contents = file_get_contents('http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/'.$main_video.'.php', False, $cxContext);
         } else {
              $contents = file_get_contents('http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/'.$main_video.'.php');
         }


        $contents = file_get_contents('http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/'.$main_video.'.php');

        $array = @unserialize(trim($contents));
        $video_thumbnail = str_replace('http://', 'https://',$array[0]["thumbnail_large"]);
    ?>

     <div class="video_thumbnail text-center">

          <img src="<?php echo $video_thumbnail ?>" alt="" class="img-responsive" />

          <div class="play js-play" data-vid="<?php echo $main_video; ?>">
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play play-btn"></span>
          </div>

     </div>
```

The large thumbnail is 640px

Apparently this is the old API. I should be using the new API if I want to load larger thumbnails.

https://developer.vimeo.com/api

I can't seem to find how to do it with the 'NEW' API.

Does anyone know how to load thumbnails with the new API, are there any examples of how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the new API to fetch video information.
For instance go to https://developer.vimeo.com/api/playground/videos/
and put in a video id and make the call.

It will return a json result. The section 'pictures' will have all available thumbnails you can fetch.

Here is the pictures section for an authenticated call to https://api.vimeo.com/videos/111096137

```
"pictures": {
    "uri": "/videos/111096137/pictures/495591662",
    "active": true,
    "sizes": [
        {
            "width": 100,
            "height": 75,
            "link": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/495591662_100x75.jpg"
        },
        {
            "width": 200,
            "height": 150,
            "link": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/495591662_200x150.jpg"
        },
        {
            "width": 295,
            "height": 166,
            "link": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/495591662_295x166.jpg"
        },
        {
            "width": 640,
            "height": 360,
            "link": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/495591662_640x360.jpg"
        },
        {
            "width": 960,
            "height": 540,
            "link": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/495591662_960x540.jpg"
        },
        {
            "width": 1280,
            "height": 720,
            "link": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/495591662_1280x720.jpg"
        }
    ]
},
```

You can use this info to fetch whatever sizes you want.

Comment: johnh10, thanks for the answers - I can see that I can get the json back if I enter the video id on the page you linked but how do I actually make the call from my page to get that json. I'm pulling the video form a database so I need to use it to make the call to vimeo to get the thumbnail.

Comment: Perhaps you can plug in the official PHP library for Vimeo. https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php

Comment: What @johnh10 didn't tell is that you first need to create an app with Vimeo, then get your API keys and secret and then make a request with for example Curl using PHP.

Comment: Do you know a way to get the pictures immediately after upload? Because it seems that vimeo returns pictures after some time

Comment: I assume it takes some time for them to generate the thumbnails and disperse it across their CDN network.